# "links of document" or "links to document"?

Tags: prepositions

> Below are the links of assessment document of software A and software B

Someone here on Stack Exchange answered that there should "links to assessment" instead "links of assessment document". He seems right but I am wondering why there should be "links to" instead of "links of"

Comment: I guess you didn't read the [big yellow banner](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KCj53.png). Please improve your question or else it will be put [on hold](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) again.

Comment: @probablyme: This isn't [the same question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/95273/confused-between-singular-and-plural), although part of it is, and I've edited that out.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes, it is not the same question, but the issue is the same. Seems like this can be answered using a dictionary. So, I suspect it might be closed again.

Comment: @probablyme: I had tried dictionary before coming asking question here but couldn't find the appropriate answer. I have got my answer and now I am query has been resolved. Let me know if you want me to delete this question but I believe there are more people who will be having the same question

Comment: No, I don't have a problem with your post. I was trying to help you prevent having your question put "on hold". You should not delete questions/post once you've received answers.

Comment: @probablyme Sorry, I mis-understood you. Actually my question had two questions. Should I use document or documents in below sentence? "Below are links to the assessment documents for Software A and Software B" or Below are links to the assessment document for Software A and Software B"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be "links to" because "links of" means that the "assessment document[s]" has links (which are the subject of this sentence), while "links to" means that there are links present on the current page that redirect you to the documents. Here are some examples that exemplify the difference better.

> The river of the ocean was freshwater.

Although this sentence is a bit different than your question, it still is pretty similar usage-wise. In this sentence, the ocean has a river that is freshwater, which doesn't make much sense because a body of water cannot possess another body of water.

> The river to the ocean was freshwater.

This sentence has a different meaning. Now, there is a river that (it is assumed) flows into the ocean and is freshwater. Think of the link as the river and the documents as the ocean.

---

This difference in meaning is caused by the different prepositions used, *of* and *to*. *Of* makes the word "document" genitive (a noun case), while *to* makes the word accusative. In English, we use *to* because it is saying that the link causes a "motion toward" the document it to which it redirects you. *Of* is possessive primarily, so it cannot serve this purpose, even colloquially.